# How do I prevent an optimizing compiler from disrupting interrupt free critical sections?

Tags: c, optimization, embedded

I have some C macros that disable and enable interrupts so that I can define critical sections of code.  I want to ensure that the optimizer complies with the operations and does not move them or remove them.

```
#define ARM_INT_KEY_TYPE         unsigned int
#define ARM_INT_LOCK(key_)   ({ \
    asm("MRS %0,cpsr" : "=r" (key_)); \
    asm("MSR cpsr_c,#(0x1F | 0x80 | 0x40)"); \
})
#define ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key_) asm("MSR cpsr_c,%0" : : "r" (key_))
```

The usage is as follows:

```
int init_i2c(p_device_i2c dev){

// Interrupts are enabled
doSomething();

ARM_INT_KEY_TYPE key;
ARM_INT_LOCK(key);

// Interrupts are disabled
pMX27_GPIO i2c_clk = (pMX27_GPIO)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR | I2C_CLK_PORT);
pMX27_GPIO i2c_sda = (pMX27_GPIO)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR | I2C_DATA_PORT);

i2c_clk->GIUS   &= ~(1 << I2C_CLK_PIN);         // I2C Signals
i2c_sda->GIUS   &= ~(1 << I2C_DATA_PIN);        // I2C Signals

ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key);
// Interrupts ON again

// Wait for stable
ARM_delay_clocks(5000);

i2c_stop(dev);
```

The code works as expected with optimization turned off but I suspect that there may be problems with optimization turned ON.

Will adding volatile to the asm statements do the trick?

```
#define ARM_INT_UNLOCK(key_) asm volatile ("MSR cpsr_c,%0" : : "r" (key_))
```

Comment: _suspect_ or _found_? :)

Comment: Just suspect so far.  I have been bitten by optimization side-effects in the past so I am being careful

Comment: @sarnold Well there's a difference between "will always work" and "will work on this specific code with this specific compiler every tuesday", so asking for some documentation that guarantees the behavior is a good idea for such things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `asm volatile` is the correct way to write this macro.  You can easily check the behavior by stepping through this code on debugger and watching the order of operations at the assembly level.  Or, you can just visually inspect the disassembly output for your function.

Here's some useful gcc documentation on inline asm

http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.4

Answer (score 0):

you only need volatile attribute on the key variable.